# Case insensitive function arguments

Tags: php

Is there a way to make php function arguments case insensitive? Right now I am looking for the word "Crossing" however "crossing" does not match. How can I make this argument case insensitive so I don't have to || each type of casing it could be put in as (if possible)

Function:

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== false);
}
```

PHP:

```
if(endsWith($searchResults, "Crossing")) {
    $searchResults = str_replace("Crossing", "Xing", $searchResults);
}
```

This was resolved using the following:

```
if(stripos($searchResults, "Crossing")) {
    $searchResults = str_ireplace("Crossing", "Xing", $searchResults);
}
```

Comment: `stripos()` is a case-insensitive version of `strpos()`.

Comment: And also for replace... http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

Comment: Thanks, I've updated that. However my endsWith function needs case insensitive arguments

Comment: Yes, check for `Crossing` case-insensitive with `stripos()` and then replace case-insensitive `Crossing` using `str_ireplace()`.  You need both.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. That took care of it for me @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for strnatcasecmp()

```
if( strnatcasecmp($varA, $varB) )
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcasecmp.php

You can also just use strtolower() or strtoupper() for comparisons. Example:

```
if( 'test' == strtolower($variable) )
```

I personally just use the later in general as long as I know what is expected, but for comparison of two true variables where case is non-sensitive strnatcasecmp() is the way to go.

Comment: He's searching for a substring, not comparing the whole string.